# Attempting to install SuiteCRM plugins on localhost leads to invalid URLs

Tags: suitecrm

I am exploring SuiteCRM and have to that end deployed SuiteCRM 7.13.4 on localhost using XAMPP with all appropriate software versions of PHP and so on. Everything works thus far. I can reach and operate the site, successfully installed a language packet. But once I went ahead and wanted to install third party plugins from the SuiteCRM store (in particular the MS Teams integration and the Office 365 plugin) I am met with a message that my server URL is invalid (see image below). I am absolutely clueless as to the cause of this.

[error message of the office 365 plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpHul.png)
[error of the MS teams integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXvnK.png)

Well, I expected the installation to run through first try but that wasn't the case.
Well, first I considered SSL the culprit. Fixed that, but installing plugins still didn't work.
Then I tried to activate CORS and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `MS Teams Integration` error is due to the `HTTPS://subdomain.domain.com` restriction. Since, their documentation refers to SugarOnDemand URL, i.e.,

> https://implicit.sugarondemand.com

so you need to create a `Virtual Host` on your machine (in the same format as above) and then, add that vhost URL as the `CRM Address`.

2. If the issue still persists, then, open the .htaccess file on the SuiteCRM instance and allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing as follows:

> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"

3. Lastly, the `Callbacks` from the `Teams` integration will not work in certain scenarios do to localhost setup. Therefore, it is better to deploy the SuiteCRM instance on a development server (on the `www`) to get 100% working integration.